# Use only audio when mixing compositing and sequencer in post processing

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

I created a nice movie layout using only the Node editor. I added an mp3 audio file via the video sequence editor. Selected Both compositing and sequence in post processing under render properties and clicked the animation button and got a nice mp4 movie.

When I replace my mp3 file with a movie clip (containing both audio and video) in the video sequence editor and hide the movie by clicking the eye and set opacity to zero + moving the clip outside the start and end frame interval, I get an undesired result. The generated output movie does not contain any video, only audio.

Comment: Have you tried just deleting the movie strip you don't need?

Comment: That seems to solve it. A few days ago, I tried your solution and it did not work, because the associated audio track was automatically deleted. Now I tried it again and when I delete the video, the audio track remained.

Comment: You probably had both strips selected, with the movie strip active. It is not always very clear that a strip is selected (could be visually a bit more clear perhaps).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of hiding the movie clip in such an laborious way, just select it and delete it. Make sure you have only the movie clip selected, and nothing else.